Ubuntu 22.04.5 - Final Point Release
I note that 22.04.5 is touted as the final point release. While I understand that security updates etc. will continued to be issued until Apr 2027 for Ubuntu 22.04 (or longer with Ubuntu Pro), is Kernel 6.8 the last kernel that will be back-ported to 22.04? Or will there be additional kernel updates in the future?

According to the standard Ubuntu LTS lifetime model,

Ubuntu 22.0.5 should be the final point release, and
Therefore kernel 6.8 should indeed be the final HWE kernel for 22.04

Canonical has not, so far, announced any change to that model.

The wording I use in text I write is "last scheduled" release.
eg.

FYI: This is the last scheduled media release for jammy or 22.04

which I used in some flavor annoucements

https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-22-04-5-lts-released/5136
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-22-04-5-released/28214

I don't use that text on official announcements, as we use prepared text only (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/09/13/ubuntu-22-04-5-lts-released/)
however IF because of security fixes, additional releases are required, new media will be created, eg.
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/
shows the the release of .6 media for 20.04, and I've posted details on releases up to .7 from memory.
The extra or non-scheduled releases go through the same process, just have slightly different reasons, such as

Unlike previous point releases, 20.04.6 is a refresh of the amd64 installer media after recent key revocations, re-enabling their usage on Secure Boot enabled systems.

which was from 20.04.6.  If they're made after the first three years, no flavor ISOs will be produced, thus you'll note no mention of flavors in the 20.04.6 release.
Please note point releases relate to MEDIA, and not kernels. There are HWE kernel changes that occur only on .2 thru .5 point releases (not .1 or .6+), so your question is mixing two different things.
If there are further unscheduled point releases for 22.04, they'll contain the same 5.15 GA or 6.8 HWE kernels but with further patches as required to correct the issue that caused the  new media to be required.

eg.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/08/30/ubuntu-24-04-1-lts-released/ shows the 24.04.1 point release, but kernel is identical to 24.04 ISOs except for the security fixes which have been applied. Kernel changes will be found in 24.04.2 thru 24.04.5 MEDIA only with HWE changes only on media using HWE kernels.
